# How can I get the original request url in errback using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy script for crawling a list of websites from a database, and my aim is to find if a certain element is present on the website and write the data back to the database.

I order the database by the urls, so I need to get the original request url in order to write the data to the correct database entry. When everything goes well, there is no problem, I can just use response.request.url with no issues in the callback function. However in case of an error (timeouts mostly) my script calls the errback function.

My question is, how can I access the original url in the errback function, since I do not pass the response to it, only error? I don't need any data from the website, just to update the database with the knowledge that there was some type of error, which is easy enough, but without the original request url I cannot do that.

Is there an easy way to access the original request url in errback?

This is how I call the request:

```
yield Request(start_urls, callback=self.parse, errback=self.errback)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=url#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing), you can access it like this:

```py
class ErrbackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        # with the response
        url = failure.value.response.url
        # with the request
        url = failure.request.url
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` object contains original `scrapy.Request` object

```
import scrapy
...
class CustomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
...

...

    def errback(self, response):
        origin_url = response.request.url
```

**UPDATE** 
Checked [documentarion link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing).
And checked again in debugger.
[image]

`errback` operates with `Failure` object. However As `Failure` object contains original `request` object as well as `HttpResponse` objects from regular callbacks - my approach also will work.

Comment: Just one nitpick (although it does not change the answer): I would rather call it `failure` instead of `response` ([like in the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing)), because it receives a slightly different object.

Comment: This answer + the first comment (changing response to failure) did the trick. Thank you!